# If f is entire and for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$, $f^{(n)}(z) = 0$ for some n, then f is a polynomial.

Tags: complex-analysis

I saw the other answers to this question from a year ago but I'm still quite confused. I have tried using identity theorem and several of its corollaries, factoring the nth derivative of f, and more, but every time I assert something I realize that it relies only on one point z having a derivative vanish, rather than all points in $\mathbb{C}$ having some derivative vanish. Any insight into the start of this problem, or a theorem I might use?

Comment: Would you care to share a link to the question?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/943952/prove-that-f-is-a-polynomial-if-one-of-the-coefficients-in-its-taylor-expansio

Comment: Does $n$ depend on $z$?

Comment: Yes, n depends on z.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Show that since $D=\{z: |z|\leq 1\}$ is uncountable, there must be an $n$ such that $f^{(n)}(z)=0$ for infinitely many $z\in D$.

Comment: Would this mean that $\{ z \in \mathbb{C} : f^{(n)}(z) = 0 \}$ has a limit point in $\mathbb{C}$, so $f^{(n)} \equiv 0$ in $\mathbb{C}$ ?

Comment: Yes, that was the idea. @mathiest

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Let $E_n = \{z\in \mathbb C : f^{(n)}(z) = 0\}.$ Then $\mathbb C = \cup_n E_n.$ Hence some $E_n$ is uncountable.

Answer (score 0):

We can establish a relation
$$ zR j \iff f^{(j)}(z) = 0
$$
This relation is left-total, so $\bigcup_{j \geq 0} R^{-1}[\{j\}] = \mathbb{C}$. Since $\mathbb{C}$ is uncountable, one of the $R^{-1}[\{j\}]$ is uncountable, so $f^{(j)}$ has uncountably many zeroes.

Since in $\mathbb{R}^n$, any uncountable set has a limit point, we can use [An improvement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem#An_improvement) to derive that $f^{(j)} = 0$.

Hence $f$ is a polynomial.